# MSTSCLib.DLL BadImageFormatException, RDP control not working on 32bit OS

Tags: visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

In my application (vs 2012) I'm using

> Microsoft RDP Client Control

(COM) to connect remotely to a machine. It's working all well unless I run my exe on a 32bit OS, then BadImageFormatException is thrown!

Error log:

> Could not load file or assembly Interop.MSTSCLib or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the files specified.

1- I tried different versions of the COM (Microsoft RDP Client Control version 2 through 10), plus "Microsoft Terminal Services Client Control"

2- I tried to set the target platform to Any CPU, x86, x64

3- I tried to embed the library

I have to make sure this app works on both 64 and 32 bit OS, Any Ideas??

Comment: Don't just copy the EXE file, you have to copy the Interop file as well.  The exception message you quoted does not match the exception type, that's just a file-not-found message.  The machine must have the correct .NET Framework version installed, whatever you used.

Comment: But I added the used library to the System32 folder, before ading them it wouldn't work on any OS, bu after I added them it only worked on 64bit OS.

Comment: Never ever copy files to system32, the CLR never looks there anyway.

Comment: What should I have done then if I didn't found the DLL there??

Comment: Copy *all* the files from your bin\Release directory to the install directory on the target machine.

Comment: It did help!! :D
I only built my app with target platform x86 and copied the DLLs within the same path of my exe
Thank you :D

Please add this as a solution to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here, in the second answer:
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a92a204-81fe-4c6f-bfc3-ef04dc932ed0/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-interopactiveds-version1000-cultureneutral?forum=netfx64bit)

But all I did is built my app with target CPU x86 and copied DLLs within same path of my exe, and all worked well